# DLL response is too slow in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll, debugging, settings

I use a 3rd party DLL in my VB.NET project (VS2005) that responds to slow and give wrong values in debug mode. In run-time mode everything works as expected.

I do understand that there are something going on in the debug mode which makes the DLL communication slow. This behavior makes it hard to debug the application correctly.

Is there any way to force VS to communicate with the DLL in "run-time" mode during debugging but let the rest of the project be in control of the debugger?

---

I found a setting that resolved my issue:

Project Properties > Debug > Enable Debuggers > select "Enable unmanaged code debugging".

Now the DLL communication flowed smoothly. The DLL I use is a middleware between my app and a USB device. There is no Debug/Release version of the DLL.

Comment: Honestly, don't trust the correctness of the release dll if the debug dll is provably wrong...

Comment: There is only one DLL provided from a 3rd party company. And it works now, see my answer below.

Comment: @Magnus please remove your answer from your question, and instead post it as an answer, then accept it (click the tick next to it).

Comment: @tomfanning I loved to do that but Jeff Atwood moved my answer to my question and deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the debug DLL for the release one, either by switching files or by telling the linker/build process to only use the release one, but like the comment above I'd suspect there's some funky stuff going on in both.

Comment: Probably worth removing this answer now the OP has clarified the question.